# Is there a way to do partition by on top of partition by in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have recently started getting back to ORACLE SQL world. I am trying to figure out something as below.

Let's say you have **STUDENT** table as below.

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT where Name = 'Jill' order by Rank desc;
```

| Name | Group | Rank | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jill | S_504 | 5 | 2 |
| Jill | S_504 | 5 | 2 |
| Jill | S_504 | 5 | 2 |
| Jill | S_501_1_A | 5 | 3 |
| Jill | S_501_1_A | 5 | 3 |
| Jill | S_501_1_A | 5 | 3 |
| Jill | S_502_2_A | 4 | 4 |
| Jill | S_502_2_A | 4 | 4 |
| Jill | S_502_2_A | 4 | 4 |
| Jill | S_500 | 4 | 5 |
| Jill | S_500 | 4 | 5 |
| Jill | S_500 | 4 | 5 |
| Jill | S_507_1_A | 3 | 6 |
| Jill | S_507_1_A | 3 | 6 |
| Jill | S_507_1_A | 3 | 6 |
| Jill | S_503_2_A | 3 | 7 |
| Jill | S_503_2_A | 3 | 7 |
| Jill | S_503_2_A | 3 | 7 |
| Jill | S_509 | 2 | 8 |
| Jill | S_509 | 2 | 8 |
| Jill | S_509 | 2 | 8 |
| Jill | S_405 | 2 | 9 |
| Jill | S_405 | 2 | 9 |
| Jill | S_405 | 2 | 9 |
| Jill | S_706 | 1 | 10 |
| Jill | S_706 | 1 | 10 |
| Jill | S_706 | 1 | 10 |

Above table has one student, which belongs to multiple **Groups**. Now, Each of these groups are having different Ranking of their own - based on which Priority column is populated.

For e.g. **S_501** and **S_501_1_A** both groups are having same `Rank`, It is completely Okay if S_501 was given **priority** 3 and S_501_1_A was given **priority** 2 - Meaning for same ranking, order of Priority does not matter.

You see I have sorted the result set by **Rank** Column in descending order. Just for the sake of understanding. I would like to populate the **Priority** column as shown in above table. Assume the **Priority** column is **yet** to be created or an output.

I tried `1+dense_rank() over (partition by Name, Group order by Rank desc)` but it just sets Priority to 2 for all. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I feel like first I have to do `partition by Name, Rank` and then on top of it I have to apply `dense_rank() over (partition by Name, Group Order by Rank DESC)`.

Can you please help me out ? or is there any approach to achieve this ?

**NOTE:** Priority starts with value 2.

Comment: It is not clear what is the rule to assign priority, because you didn't specify any ordering of `group` column.  The above output for the `select` statement provided may be just a luck and groups may appear out of any order in the output. Please provide the case for groups out of order or clarify the requirement

Comment: I just edited the 'Group' column. Appreciate your help !

Comment: Again, it's still not clear why `S_504` appear at the top: table is a **set**, it doesn't have any order of rows and no any tricks of `order by` preserve stable sort order unless you explicitly specify ordering without ties.

Comment: This is just sample data. It does not have anything to do with what is on top or at bottom.  'Jill' is part of multiple groups among which 'S_504' and 'S_501_1_A' is having higher ranking... That's it !!

Comment: Then I do not understand the reason of your comment for the answer: as long as `group` means nothing for ranking, it's is completely irrelevant if it is present in the ordering or not from the algorithm's point of view.  But it is used to assign different  priority for the same ranking

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

Some sample data (with `ID` added, just for sorting purposes):

```
SQL> with student (id, name, grp, rnk) as
  2    (select  1, 'Jill', 's_501', 5 from dual union all
  3     select  2, 'Jill', 's_501', 5 from dual union all
  4     select  3, 'Jill', 's_501', 5 from dual union all
  5     select  4, 'Jill', 's_501_1_a', 5 from dual union all
  6     select  5, 'Jill', 's_501_1_a', 5 from dual union all
  7     select  6, 'Jill', 's_501_1_a', 5 from dual union all
  8     select  7, 'Jill', 's_502_2_a', 4 from dual union all
  9     select  8, 'Jill', 's_502_2_a', 4 from dual union all
 10     select  9, 'Jill', 's_502_2_a', 4 from dual union all
 11     select 10, 'Jill', 's_503', 4 from dual union all
 12     select 11, 'Jill', 's_503', 4 from dual union all
 13     select 12, 'Jill', 's_503', 4 from dual union all
 14     select 13, 'Jill', 's_503_1_a', 3 from dual union all
 15     select 14, 'Jill', 's_503_1_a', 3 from dual union all
 16     select 15, 'Jill', 's_503_1_a', 3 from dual union all
 17     select 16, 'Jill', 's_503_2_a', 3 from dual union all
 18     select 17, 'Jill', 's_503_2_a', 3 from dual
 19    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 20  select name, grp, rnk,
 21    1 + dense_rank() over (partition by name order by grp, rnk desc) priority
 22  from student
 23  order by id;

NAME GRP              RNK   PRIORITY
---- --------- ---------- ----------
Jill s_501              5          2
Jill s_501              5          2
Jill s_501              5          2
Jill s_501_1_a          5          3
Jill s_501_1_a          5          3
Jill s_501_1_a          5          3
Jill s_502_2_a          4          4
Jill s_502_2_a          4          4
Jill s_502_2_a          4          4
Jill s_503              4          5
Jill s_503              4          5
Jill s_503              4          5
Jill s_503_1_a          3          6
Jill s_503_1_a          3          6
Jill s_503_1_a          3          6
Jill s_503_2_a          3          7
Jill s_503_2_a          3          7

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Nope, This expects GROUP to be organized in ascending order. I do not want to do that, priority should only be assigned using RANK. I do not want to sort groups first and then sort the rank.

Comment: What is "this" (that expects ...)? PRIORITY values match what you posted as expected result, so ... I'm not sure I understand your comment. BTW, did you run code I suggested on your database (real data)? What happened?

Comment: 'This expects' meaning 'Your given query expects...'. In the table shared by me, Values present in "Group" column are just 'Happened to be' in ascending order. If you change the values, then also my result set should not change at all.

Comment: Aha. In that case, I suggest you post data that isn't misleading. How are we (the community) supposed what you really have?

Comment: Thanks for bringing out an important observation. I just edited the table for better understanding. Hope this should clear out any confusion. Thanks again !

Comment: OK. What rule sets PRIORITY (for the first 3 rows in edited sample data) to 2, and to 3 for the next 3 rows if they share the same NAME and RANK? You said that GROUP doesn't matter, but - something *has to* because - otherwise - you can't tell which rows will get which PRIORITY.

Comment: As mentioned in question, "Same rank" and "different groups" , priority can be in any order. BUT, "Different Rank" and "Different Group" - Priority must be changed to the next value in order.

Comment: Let me simplify again, hope this helps. "Higher the ranking value" - "Lower the priority value"

Comment: It's quite late over here so I'm probably not getting it right, but - does that mean that *any switch of value* in either GROUP and/or RANK would do? `1 + dense_rank() over (partition by name order by rnk desc, grp)`? (your last comment: OK, but the first 6 rows share the same RANK so the only thing you have left is GROUP).

Comment: Yes. As long as "Higher the ranking value" - "Lower the priority value" this is persisted.

Comment: Did you try code I posted in my previous comment? Does it do any good?

Comment: Just tried and validated. Looks like it is working ! ! Thanks again .